# Ceridian HR-Payroll Source SQL error

Tags: windows-server-2003, database, sql

We are using an old piece of software from Ceridian called Source this is a HR Payroll piece of software. I cannot phone their support as we no longer have a contract but use the software for archive data. Most of the program works but when I use the print then Preview function we are getting error messages:

SQLGETSQLQUERY: Cannot open SQL server.
and
Error in Main CrwSetPrintJobFormulaAndLocation.

This is running on Server 2003.

I have searched everywhere for a solution but to no avail,  any ideas?

Comment: You can't expect us to be able to help you with the provided information.  There are far to many things it could be and its unlikely anyone but a very small set of people could answer this.

Comment: I placed this on here with the off chance that somebody may have come across this problem, or at least an educated suggestion like techie007 has posted.

Answer (score 3):

Those are pretty vague internal errors.

It appears the SQLGETSQLQUERY method failed because it can't "open" the SQL server.

- Does the SQL server exist?
- Is it at the place it expects it to be?
- Do the tables exist?
- Are they corrupted?

It also appears that something is getting an "Error" when attempting to set the CrwSetPrintJobFormulaAndLocation property.

- Do you have any printers installed?
- Do you have any now missing printers referenced in the payroll program?

Really though, I think you'll need to call their support (and pony up the cash if it's important enough).